# TableViewCell is froze with an empty dataSource array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib, nib

I make a request to the server for fetching data, then set its data to my array for dealing with TableView.

Sometimes happens issue when one cell or few cells is froze despite the fact that server response is an **empty** dataSource array is an **empty** too, but cells stacks anyway. And still on the screen till I closed. Also tableView contentOffset is changed:

[image]

> The screenshot shows froze tableViewCell. But dataSource array is an **empty**, **numberOfRowsInSection** in section also equal to 0.

Some details:

- `tableView.reloadData()` is called from the main thread;
- ViewController lie in TabBarViewController;
- I inspect mine model object class on Retain cycle, seems everything is fine;
- I use xib for the cell. The cell has a custom content view. All IBOutlets in Cell class has weak references.

Please, help me to understand where I'm wrong

**EDIT:**

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let numberOfRowsInSection = items?.count else {
            messageLabel?.text = messageText
            return 0
        }

        return numberOfRowsInSection
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        // Cell settings

        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your datasources of tableview.

Comment: Consider adding related code.

Comment: iPeter, Ratul Sharker, I added a few lines of code. Will it be enough?

Comment: Are you missing `optional func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` overrride? because if you do - the default implementation returns `1` which might be invalid for your usecase

Comment: is it same problem with this code? `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 0
    }`

Comment: Of course not. If `numberOfRowsInSection` is 0 everything works fine. And the bug that I describe happens not always, but sometimes...

Comment: It is not bug, all because of this `guard let numberOfRowsInSection = items?.count else {
            messageLabel?.text = messageText
            return 0
        }

        return numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: I think yo u do tableview.reload when you not finish clean items array, that's why some times that work fine

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are missing data source method

```
optional func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614860-numberofsections

> The number of sections in tableView. The default value is 1.

This should break your implementation when you have 0 items in your array. Based on your structure it could look similar to

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    guard let arr = items else { return 0 }
    return arr.count == 0 ? 0 : 1
}
```

Comment: I have the problem with number Of Rows In Section, not with number Of Sections

Comment: Also as I wrote above "Sometimes happens issue when one cell or few cells is froze"

Comment: I can only assess your issue based on provided information and code. Since you don't provide your full data source implementation I have to assume the setup is wrong hence my answer. I am happy to help but you need to provided us with more implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    // Cell settings

    return cell

}
```

You are returning a cell without dequeueing it.

If you instantiate a cell yourself the TableView doesn't have control over it, so it is not able to reuse it after you update your data source.

Please change your code like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Identifier", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

    // Cell settings

    return cell

}
```

But also make sure you are [registering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) the cell before that, in your viewDidLoad probably.

Something like:

```
tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"Identifier")
```

Comment: It seems the "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int" returns num of cells, but not the "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell". Also as I wrote above "Sometimes happens issue when one cell or few cells is froze"

Comment: if there are no cells, then `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` should not be called at all. Maybe you forgot to call `tableView.reloadData()` after updating the data source? Besides that another problem is the instantiation of the cells, you should not instantiate them manually.

Comment: I knew. Therefore didn't understand your answer. I didn't forget to call `tableView.reloadData()`. I should add this to this to the explanation, thanks.

Comment: But you are still instantiating (creating) cells on your own. This part specifically: `UITableViewCell()`. I still suggest you change your `cellForRowAt` like in my answer.